# How can I scrape WHO influenza data without using Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm on a team that's working on a number of disease modeling efforts, and we're wanting to collect historical weekly influenza data from the WHO on a number of countries. The data are nominally available at https://apps.who.int/flumart/Default?ReportNo=12, but the website and underlying API are built in a really strange way that make it difficult to scrape.

I am aware of https://github.com/mobinalhassan/WHO-Data-Downloader, which is some nice open source code that's written to collect the data, but it uses Selenium, and I'm hoping to avoid Selenium and just use pure [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) since Selenium can be kind of a pain to setup.

### The WHO FluMart website

The [WHO FluMart website](https://apps.who.int/flumart/Default?ReportNo=12) first shows a simple form that allows a user to select 1 or more countries and a time frame of interest, and when the user hits the "Display report" button, the website queries a backend to show data in a table. Depending on the query, it can take 10-30+ seconds for the query to return. Here's a screenshot:

[image: WHO FluMart website screenshot]

My goal is to collect the data shown in this table for a number of countries.

### API oddities (AFAIK)

When a user fills out the form at the top and hits "Display report", a `POST` request is submitted to https://apps.who.int/flumart/Default?ReportNo=12 that includes the obvious data, as well as some not-obvious data. Here's an example from the above screenshot:

```
ScriptManager1=ScriptManager1|ctl_ReportViewer$ctl09$Reserved_AsyncLoadTarget
__EVENTTARGET=ctl_ReportViewer$ctl09$Reserved_AsyncLoadTarget
__EVENTARGUMENT
__LASTFOCUS
__VIEWSTATE=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
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=15FCE702
__EVENTVALIDATION=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
ddlFilterBy=1
lstSearchBy=Mexico
ctl_list_YearFrom=2017
ctl_list_WeekFrom=1
ctl_list_YearTo=2021
ctl_list_WeekTo=53
ctl_ReportViewer$ctl03$ctl00
ctl_ReportViewer$ctl03$ctl01
ctl_ReportViewer$ctl10=ltr
ctl_ReportViewer$ctl11=standards
ctl_ReportViewer$AsyncWait$HiddenCancelField=False
ctl_ReportViewer$ctl04$ctl03$ddValue=1
ctl_ReportViewer$ctl04$ctl05$ddValue=1
ctl_ReportViewer$ToggleParam$store
ctl_ReportViewer$ToggleParam$collapse=false
ctl_ReportViewer$ctl05$ctl00$CurrentPage
ctl_ReportViewer$ctl05$ctl03$ctl00
ctl_ReportViewer$ctl08$ClientClickedId
ctl_ReportViewer$ctl07$store
ctl_ReportViewer$ctl07$collapse=false
ctl_ReportViewer$ctl09$VisibilityState$ctl00=None
ctl_ReportViewer$ctl09$ScrollPosition
ctl_ReportViewer$ctl09$ReportControl$ctl02
ctl_ReportViewer$ctl09$ReportControl$ctl03
ctl_ReportViewer$ctl09$ReportControl$ctl04=100
__ASYNCPOST=true
```

I figured that I could whip out `requests` and issue a simple query like this:

```py
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
  data = {'lstSearchBy': 'Mexico',
          'ctl_list_YearFrom': '2017',
          'ctl_list_WeekFrom': '1',
          'ctl_list_YearTo': '2021',
          'ctl_list_WeekTo': '53'}
  r = s.post('https://apps.who.int/flumart/Default?ReportNo=12', data=data)
  print(r.text)
```

Unfortunately, rather than returning the table in the screenshot, this query simply returns the form at the top of the screenshot. At this point, I start to think that some of those other `POST` parameters must actually be required (`__EVENTTARGET`, `__VIEWSTATE`, `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR`, etc.).

Looking at the original form that's returned when I visit https://apps.who.int/flumart/Default?ReportNo=12, I see this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1"><title>
    WHO FLUMART OUTPUTS
</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="./Default?ReportNo=12" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="u38eXuRq1rlncPtmBq04xgVPASJukKZ8QVDUb
...
```

(this is truncated for brevity)

Here, there are a number of hidden inputs with names that correspond to the `POST` request that Firefox issues (`__EVENTTARGET`, `__EVENTARGUMENT`, `__LASTFOCUS`, `__EVENTVALIDATION`, etc.). This made me think that what I could do is just grab those values and then tack them onto the `POST` data like this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.Session() as s:
  r = s.get('https://apps.who.int/flumart/Default?ReportNo=12')
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
  data = {'lstSearchBy': 'Mexico',
          'ctl_list_YearFrom': '2017',
          'ctl_list_WeekFrom': '1',
          'ctl_list_YearTo': '2021',
          'ctl_list_WeekTo': '53'}
  hidden_inputs = soup.find_all('input', {'type': 'hidden'})
  for i in hidden_inputs:
    data.update({i['id']: i['value']})
  r = s.post('https://apps.who.int/flumart/Default?ReportNo=12', data=data)
  print(r.text)
```

But this unfortunately doesn't work either; I just get the same submission form.

How could I grab the table that's produced in the screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple complexities that occur when scraping this site:

1. In order to get the actual data from a request to the site's endpoint, the entire headers of the original browser's request must be sent, containing in particular the user agent and cookies.
2. The `data` payload of the `POST` request should be encoded as it is displayed in the browser's developer network settings.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

def parse_headers(s):
    return dict(i.split(': ') for i in filter(None, s.split('\n')))

def get_page_data(headers, data):
    return requests.post('https://apps.who.int/flumart/Default?ReportNo=12', headers=headers, data=data).text

def parse_table(page):
    _, _, h, *body = [list(filter(None, [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in b.select('td')])) 
        for b in page.select('table table table table tr:nth-of-type(5) table tr')]
    return [dict(zip([*filter(None, h)], i)) for i in body]

def data_format(filter_by, year_from, week_from, year_to, week_to):
    return f'ScriptManager1=ScriptManager1%7Cctl_ReportViewer%24ctl09%24Reserved_AsyncLoadTarget&ddlFilterBy=1&lstSearchBy={filter_by}&ctl_list_YearFrom={year_from}&ctl_list_WeekFrom={week_from}&ctl_list_YearTo={year_to}&ctl_list_WeekTo={week_to}&ctl_ReportViewer%24ctl03%24ctl00=&ctl_ReportViewer%24ctl03%24ctl01=&ctl_ReportViewer%24ctl10=ltr&ctl_ReportViewer%24ctl11=standards&ctl_ReportViewer%24AsyncWait%24HiddenCancelField=False&ctl_ReportViewer%24ctl04%24ctl03%24ddValue=2&ctl_ReportViewer%24ctl04%24ctl05%24ddValue=1&ctl_ReportViewer%24ToggleParam%24store=&ctl_ReportViewer%24ToggleParam%24collapse=false&ctl_ReportViewer%24ctl05%24ctl00%24CurrentPage=&ctl_ReportViewer%24ctl05%24ctl03%24ctl00=&ctl_ReportViewer%24ctl08%24ClientClickedId=&ctl_ReportViewer%24ctl07%24store=&ctl_ReportViewer%24ctl07%24collapse=false&ctl_ReportViewer%24ctl09%24VisibilityState%24ctl00=None&ctl_ReportViewer%24ctl09%24ScrollPosition=&ctl_ReportViewer%24ctl09%24ReportControl%24ctl02=&ctl_ReportViewer%24ctl09%24ReportControl%24ctl03=&ctl_ReportViewer%24ctl09%24ReportControl%24ctl04=100&__EVENTTARGET=ctl_ReportViewer%24ctl09%24Reserved_AsyncLoadTarget&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=YL2qHxwNGZldOd3IRtTNxltlDxl6JtgE%2FUgHEMczO2DaO86YP7Pisi%2Boy5J38hueExXZvkZ2%2FLFWuZ8%2BJllMGS3WsrWdzb%2Fra54OnBc%2F85eyDku2qxRk3j%2FTZKeNgBLcD%2FSbHgkxV%2BnH1E%2BG4hqIkRYp5NM54%2BNIcz9rJ238WkwMpIAf5J3ZFVg7GGXBlshhMBhcNYP7EgBULJuuzXROw9ENFNvQfuImbI8nDmuXKbqD7K%2FmdTolPdaCy%2FSzguVu22ERMnf88RZlpoEKgHLbhAlATBnTeUR2RfUvInVjOpHGkfKqkAkY%2BM1foqxL9TFfp%2FRiQgTddNccF%2F1ZCC9cFQ8bGOTwJrL9ib4M5wyB6WSl0NXTgEVcSjvXxRgWnnKJivk9rk68ORGJBAsV3TRg7LXeHzqd4eShHPt7Lqacw0N2jbnBXuhirve9dvDInVlS%2FjgMGvDpwRuRxuraGD8pJP9ZWM84HcwbteRS8BVq8C1GGNN3nW2TIuoMR5PbzaPoXHBC8Qyc6bIYaLrGHP8agAO94S9pDM3Ou4CMmjkfud5hJB%2BgpnjPOfEGYbl1%2BuscA0%2BsKeVRG%2Bzn%2BJGuCKe%2F1ka4spJOwA3KUl5udfdsfb%2Fjh7m4OCTknkrmNZg2tBRa7af0cFfjeMnVpklcFnmChQsnF53ekmQN6s2wWq%2F0P1cU88Ekvh%2Bu4%2F2RYIRsabSXd8JHoRCDNyJGh0Pqj1eyLaiVruDI17nSZFFaHzzDxjM99dtoF27YXqLn5MvPYH5%2FNl9GEo8XkQvFPlXzbYkqsbncJxKUFeEpFjbwV2u3P82pkKzCK8Gpw%2Bu4vvZaq21ttY28yJZ1F0zByloEwijm9NTiy%2B7r6t8hAxJH%2F4hsBVoaZjKk49K6N%2BLWv158pQjonDEqXj%2BaCEsnJenBSjGmtq6U48AUjeYT%2FvQBcc8uQ3TLgeJMSliroiGpqJB0hK409ASPpj8LrYIGjgePtLWEYgwFoovvPJlZczri41YkdnK9hgVulHyyzrnyprMNcxNFtq3Z0Q6p5IzYsWgw3KOWEYAYsu46QMBtI0AR9eapekjzqVTEFnqNOq11o6LdMmJFLlijMtzXra2M9KvjgGZBXUt0uIMP7HfTjE4ZSEuJgWSdhqD1yk2I%2BAoNv7rwswbDGQwzqbz31QxBuiJKihLqrQ%2BP%2FhtzU8sITCW96A3KXMaRm%2Fd1q8y8yJAqeSsSOClns1We5%2BSWWjjBQqBrgVzIFPGxyXohjDHhEr2HeqIi36J1j4by01ZYY%2F%2FR8VP0zRpyjdBhOgaGQgHUB2MBpHb3oBCbLH1PfYMjgNdhEjEsah%2BLgr2pa67%2FFJSs5Q2mJEMpDOX3dsEafmp16BpmxDPppGIRkSeVzo1tV%2F1i01AHNPWTl%2B%2BQ4HnlooxF0sMoFbqYNwoRq3GgPs4zgtAnHgguf3BEZc7IyDxRs0AqUsbuRL8SxHM3heGmPJEgUx1dU%2B%2BZTg0Dn%2BhFB96XMzznj3QYEUh5sSP4CquC%2F1xR4lqO%2BbfGzpFj3m%2FjjzUZAZp5SIU2IBEvoEeX3MoJPRPZQus64NTi07qN126hbLIdOmKsVz9b7jZJxAeVTkzql6KAaGc5nW45kKWHeC7ogWmfT5yTEZFCrt00eK1htAsw3Cd62%2FMG0sCRyUwHFl608y9CQEAvZ4DFv7kRpavEXGZL3MrAm4V3L7F8pBzsA4RHIWYb%2BLDLyRukj%2Bz%2FJesjM%2FCrQu3UKR4t9KFNRV5GV26ttTuqcf%2Fj4bfLG4Yy81rmaI%2BOAoPdgzfxT3qt0zxyNiUsJAdJCeO%2Bo5EAzk4zED0kmXsPBEywPc2zjAiC77nHuWurXiHG2R1B9K9Z%2FsV8RKluVREZUN3L3WCM1rnLJrcwBLPEhCadjCYDAB9W5%2BgIiahn7OaQjGFj7WWHrlhG2uB%2B%2BlfXIfI0jVtUOUQ0eccI1QPg7Y%2BRJaBaL%2FyLGXeivuSRHZx2Un5B3CQMvbzz%2FmWZUk%2FOOJmF0bisQXOrIi9eFnUvuCPHcx%2BcIPR%2FPqIzbCqyp6TYH%2FfcyZo%2B9fJeQCu0YZ%2Bvahk%2Bv%2BbyL5CZJ5xOtxEEEm5XsUDtMRNQPv7BHcTiOifPwvAFGQENSZczwhABS7uG%2FFyrx4qp%2BJNoVJY%2Fmukz16tWYINYQLQJ7Ezc5O80fkVzWQvEBzOOOIxPkPav80B%2BdDFTf3gUqJFWyU1U%2BpwZ8YE0dROv4NMYBlvhN1q2Tw5C3JORVorcBiNX6RCnREm9OS9yZEicE9rYJ3pbUa0Kl5gG9XXDh%2FpjhQBycfHCBpbcm9IKirffCl%2B%2BU1FA0hxEtbuAbA75R4v25ooX6Bbdp7pNfA%2B0XNhtWVJsrHi%2BqZlpSVlTMEX9xSu2LMOZlLvRNSxByDDjir9oMwQ5wd5dGInKTIUHr7m4BYwTHucq%2FcvQGDXGv45ShbUyVOz8rwXBgvyc4fM438hZMnwgcNxyeha3S%2Fbkr%2Fsb7poUmFuR6xFK67Ss2RV%2FSBBGinyG%2FhPtDXGQk%2Bn2EGQ2LpCYYv0InfLxxtkXhMgRnZBPIP%2BE35nDZaVyiuemjwAHk8BjyONWFssPpccgvEiyMi9OS2Rjw2WPLixzl%2FwVxKs9LPMabLjt2Pue0LKmK9Vwzp9kbGFxiM4hZ0GC0WvvMNbugjxEkh4p9a0kJjxEDTjCbAhkwaZ2ryBnfaZPd0CEPp%2BzOXatPyH5ThWoSSve0La7xdlwP8PdU3S%2Fa58ErJ%2FF72j4Z08qZYbKXH9AvlUQrKsW3qIKnQQbA5sUduUArJJuxU9YJHPgN5Mp07lRUZIEo%2BsYmD154PYAYk6de%2FpIMvhAfOsGMMpu4tzzbUIFHDShHKgbS3Nh4kqPB8Stx5z%2Fs1S8ygVROSYWXH48WN4kVSFhEB9I4enEsE%2FdD1EEyIHeS4HrBQsh7%2FuTKtgKZNr85tkYF5rohM3r9BlT0y3D5%2FGjS2a89kasTkipdAGf5xkRZbA5xc7QGyhOcUP2VYVVrSEtuZa%2FACgjr7ymfWSfQ3ygghTd2QWvb64fPU88s%2BqZ1HEYiebmIQ3yeq%2FpgUD38XOkQL2Q%2FyW2bOub2J6i9VdFCMRKy%2BBkmzLsHWq%2Bxn6TOJbIBSnTf7qaeY6mRZIjDsLRAmwib9sV9rkuIw7Ea8TSRUZQG3J8cj%2BSLT6nfSGsxEDBBoqsGbFH2s87lDW4z0WTdL5paV2s3ZXlI40mPuYEkPq2WSNxIf8q6VYEl4FYxpuRoVLsksSfbNeJSRCxDsPRAMaNOk6L8%2FHwhCTi6CfyHjYvPHzyIyxdsJWn4aiBVbd%2Fighj0xTLmPvTT9zej%2BQEXWp0Mnq3sTJ6MMbICTlKWlv%2BrWHasd0vSb1nK%2FRHGBx3KnyYKJcnQlP7G3UZRa5APuOtfZr%2FqctNlPYpD35FqYbq94c9jWzKVA%2BHNnL5ufqzIGViXcSmY8XGJ0cuFUxRhDHpuh3em45GB8nRx399KMTXqn8bKvzihPKRBowZRowBdKTLv8juxrKU%2FV6vSWmcmdASAVesMSA96RwITCZiL8YiJ3%2FR0R%2Borv2DxruVg9ExhCqKLO6i9GOZ5wM7Yk%2Btt7XVE8l%2Fhq9nRSw5iEzcI8%2BePBR1Xrj0BI9VWV8Sx9SOoM6OIeP2ItyXiUScuqdpVe6n7b4VZOsy8BqSCIrnpWAHBMiQw6imSH7ij2jIYzOL8uXc35gM0oI3dmUpR08iou6v5mK9Fz5RbOZEeWKOpkY%2F7iLsZ7f7KdLny7vxgARXqQNAf345aOsHJISx1qFqwtC%2BITwqYVYLZT7y6K9HOlVqyaaCVNgDQytnBtOx5HWgRz9rxNOGIToejFRq1hM2sA2JdlkTzZ%2FIDowN7%2BDsit%2BtWKbTWcnCOC9nIwSaNqTVVZ61UejK5kvyhu101v4LXL2H26vLVfn1DHMjM0EAaj12Q%2F54KNVrvHEj%2BM6QdxbFZbiH5VIPWHE%2BeUJFNtuwOOdPQuen0qMjEAFrroIWXKGiZGOfUBciXn4q8cLtWHL9Eogtw7FTYc54BIpsvC5B20YLgJ%2BtEo%2F8%2F0IdB9heDY%2FSBxZMrVFskIQnHsRIYItY1W4o0xncXPzkMPpmZYGnCyWZi43Y77KdYfb4gOe3P%2BCNJLyqyu7lyL8StY8evOdUWOffRSfPBkcoTYs1d%2Fi2M3ObR6ZcbFEobBIy2LEIzKT%2BPnKC1CaMA%2FsN56T7fRZZ2vAlkKK60BY%2FQqt1SFtAkZh0kCwmBTfmWzPi5et%2FelPWZmAv4LP1M%2BT3KzAHuR%2B8bTBcn8gLXBodDvlEyWkoSKvzcNnYJqfEnqOqo%2FYZWjzXo7zZanhCOyIzDhEc0Oij9io%2FvecCighcCXN12%2B1XLflDF%2BgPZ%2B0CXH5dTcY7wBFv4AjtvNJ2bHtTz9%2BQrdu6AaC3RKG2o1ed80fSycNIkucHikb4Vxq5Y9lC%2BgA6Y3Wi7wlYC73vfdyW5uwl2ObpPkedINHad7TdaLnsBjFnlJJDYYcIsAC2Y4Gad89RsPDlJ8HJ9aPtdnM34Ai2Bt5qDLKX5vMZ6Yg9g8nakrLV9xpXHayyAf7bsBicaPdygs8wiW04vnKrfomDaU549n64V1LE3ylHCFQWbqWfxWxJNLBmmA04QnBGI8njE%2FrlIl5C00vxtjA27kzC%2BNR2i86bKE19SnPV69fm16yMI057dIAzSZsLGTC7kXSc8BAK0FtytY7Uq9VNkQDODHez06mtfhvW88INN4TR9mLZtM8qmXJyYkrDWISboKv5Aw3g0UCNtC3fyvjkZ983kTNojZO9yPh7%2BZ8HRtxGJJJ1Xuk4F5Q5Feizfbbf6wyR7G2WhFGusFN4TxWhDt%2BLpRZcqgYRSnfDbqSZNs1tBtvqBsLx%2B9O9zZ3dWJvW4GJOK1%2BN15qmoP8p985U%2FAvzNI6NZOWYZ8vnfTNEm3BcGIeH%2FxPBHaXCwVU4QLdc3McbVRsnn9n4DGMun3VHyCtpJyAQlLU0M86KXMxNPJ1AVTaCXmBuhdny2fPGTrtfa3i%2FphPpO1%2FQx6Knp96yaCJIw5Vq6Dcfcf1mw5fs3oV0reHo9A9EjMNNlTwCtthtYKmy%2B5wmC1h%2FL%2FGlwi3%2FvKU1wZLluCKREtyjUh%2F2wQ5MPKC%2BrcVMo1f016xNLCXzUx53YV87M0msdzx4LnDu5dEQciqdu0PZHALMFQZvB1cWPV54s9jLsEGewgKa2QbUt%2FEBtxF8gJ3ZMbfqtsjMkH9F3Ak%2Bu3MLImbn%2BB1TcSKyQlLiBBJbU1aHGHVAL9PDhLX%2FlE9Cb2RxkAuyENAyDwsIijXZ04dwGzeQiAS7UJ0z5MA%2FwovY8uwkmP9Lfve0b%2BIJbSxMkwW6xOBgjpYzqnSkGB6OVJM7YwyHpGTmKDV%2BZ1MuwTHcLeQl0nYviqVQ5mTlCG%2FbbePyAWjjpJ0LDGlFJF%2BBUg7ZkGLuARuorsd0ED6xgd%2BrInKvuN4bFwMPdjoqVjBtxBjlJvFlzvvJ0Ha3ZqyCytySuX7WQxIsWV%2FNe6M95DAZOpAyijtkYjyhemXDb%2B3BvoSaZjffVdx98MxgYKIllQQc1D37lSGSfaAzGP%2FnVr691px70v7ac%2F%2BJgRcUQnwmz9MVnwyrIJi4%2BpXvWbVwEtG1sTettS9EL9tOoDLp6A%2Fu%2BdKGxKfSkNA1kendoljI1oeTOVEslt9sAqSXu22uwryIEeisIkadjn%2BUU58i71scueCJfxD6D60hgPLQrzzgYsr7LOQaEwMzbdeszhOSN9S38mTTBIFiKr6UUQFE5IOj8pUhPrZyVD3%2Bpeapyoie74rH7niojSzhooZ8J49PzpXi6tsW%2BPk6ioS%2BbiXtRM1g2ROPrHCmJmO%2BFUsIJGkoVG8YyMqQeLqZ6fRQxgKaQV6Is9xGh0SO5Jz2QjxFIL1RWlMgd%2BiOMlOxiLQ7Rk%2Bg4Lrg5GhyhkzLBU5BAqOSkfNetWj95NAqWlZCvSw4Yv69FLQFPHDjzyh3eSsxOW6QXGAoYQyoIZ3ltG%2B679MilrR3DOSRE27iV8S63KeZFbGhfkd0eZ1kAhfpIpdt93pNnw%2BArQS7reZYI7gT3qhwgeyBC0Zb3aQh3DSWVLwbd6sU0eM2wmtq0GjzTAc4HKNXKflOj3LPM59ad4pDy0AjTVKs1b6RpE%2BLWRz6yfEp%2Brw2FN3uNIkXmaHwerSqpFTK%2BqDH%2Bwv3U58j%2FrtMxbcNMATcQ3euEXprdMo3QRndHFMsQIICNAKmgEFuHQea1UDnOvbbDvC6DdbRvRKE0bh9KR3C8mxzI9BQ1pgkCsnp793g2yVhXG9%2Bn9w9M31j%2B02kHzUZ%2FnTSOrO78tuI5%2F0J9m%2Ftz%2BIy3XJinMUAVpDr%2F5a4ja9LlY7xbmQp2zTkGCMDBsAI61YumnaMrq%2BYwoqIAwoGJYR9AYqK29tQdGgxkKagzslJEZM%2FWXh2bYTmpGTJ9GD9HBivlxHXwjO%2BiNbAicNzN0cUlRrwT9ueZx%2Bq5D4Om%2BE85VynNjwqZcMh8uOvJGarDs7JLQn1gNMZh3IdmgTJ62FeLnq7mQEc1RxHWgNIrBw8aen9LrRlG%2FWVi3oZKZETsWEHIqjbxTU7WqO1Aq4e8iTW1envBC0smJDYZ%2FJHi85q9u6j9KC3ZoczZPqfDm%2BOx5I%2Bz4u5XXX8EtPmqErO9CGj7%2FCxLJXqLf3SmcNp65yfQ6r72mN57dLMjxnuqLheCFTCuatRSW%2B7eBY1%2BbZQZDNELWBpL3wId5h2i3wrURG1i1J%2BnNvwhRzVsYkGQ%2BLjz%2BelYNFnUkEy00KFALzt%2Bi%2B6d3omrzod8p6YG4loKZP5UZnd%2FKbXX2JXyOefxv1T2hbtaXOYTOh6x5UX5TXNMAZCnItTsSIc%2BFR4n3Lx68KV97zi1bfTbMGZWVGhHGOFQlDeuJnmgqopjyU9jW2hIQ54uptztbv2YrkA7bE5OQzsepSMqiE2M06QGdIJX3Q4nwtB7Pycq%2FcQ2vdNH0BeRJL1wDyf4cjJ2%2BcZAd7g%2Fl7xWizZ8noLkMIg%2BYWovoxNj%2B5gHsIDzinnSjp%2Bhg2457vHeODMVl%2F0bd0OdSwrlHVHNyfBW2Iu8EcyX7oPsLsvrBhq0r7ovtcGZLpDZkYvHSh168BaMy%2FHOr%2BmJjUOXGo77%2BQRI%2BZRMaLil6k4KVyQLGSsrvKKM0691e8a8o%2B8MaH1T%2FWa%2BPnOuwcd6bzWprwFu8CFvTmcxJQGZotkSr9%2FT1WE6qjB9b4eYM7zwfJhe%2BRoCdOKZxarz98foU8XvfspsSzfko301PvyH%2B9to9sR5uqmd%2FzH7NlHPtj2hWKipJMKiK6iOq6Ix4U8%2FOVKW1w0sDzFMDyj0olCGnPDkiZKDh7Zm%2B3U6GwgM7C0atlM8y9oTlZ5j5MnaLs6Ht6mVJswMxXCtnk8X9m3LCLWf8LJZ9wQhJd3fLOYippqVIbVbV5zqYkXLbj2xrkXiP%2FyQnK99a0jnMghFM%2FTTWH0qL%2B1sLTNRyXZcuOtVzD9By6VBmPQYA3iPMCZUfOtOPXymx%2Bd0jbnok8ATwav86yrp6WRQyTYs7%2Bjc6OlRVvEWq2MvYIIL3RRHAq%2BrxK%2Bvphp%2F00ItztZ%2FxxoyqCqxWLAgsnKkDcHyO16sE4lQ9Y%2Fr%2FmstTrrb5c4%2BA3WkA93lPUXsll2Rqi5OzvYWe76v1m7jDNU2n57x8o8wCyr18fNt6L9zVCiWH0WzNvBWhiES%2BH11ZhkhwDANYXrKFpUiPfiAEu1aHTAoyOsBNXdIJ5GbmjD%2BJYhowcAjcKuYIuOvTdO%2FnQUHgF4GWz7g6vwzYq5GDIpjJIBly7jarBWFjYN8vDQkp43Qs%2BapAQErPZSgFAODvFM2UcMO6CrVeLjjEmDySgETwflBVPDUWz9sJpAXkNs%2Fs1pX79Qm%2B0Wt9B738GQvFEpUxuYDPWemBhVsS74Udr0m3g%2Bb6PqXKvpVaCKXG3yi%2BOX8smXgl1cefnU5CCNYvJ75VnlgJTQyBezF%2BV98VQDdwXKAFCzRKw9PraNhbVhniYN0RBuZuQ7m7Wc6Sr%2FmDJX2P8tvtgDNNB2M52PN%2FygmSWhGibdG1yLkwUc%2FrGf8CjTNv5m04Iam%2BzWaxp%2FIDhs9KvgOs7PSlBSkWlyhFSCEcp%2FmMGmhlC2ZwxkI8RDB0U1mPBZp2zhtbvhLCZWdzfopfUPSPiSb0Vg%2BbhM%2BI2CWpB8HsSyxUj%2BK90fF2Dtl0ssMMBFt%2FTiz9LZOOVKZAdjjtD1EUhghQXq9i227KbI1zkF2I1eFQnN3hKMpAFIFIbxKacWu08QsQxyMhRjNL4BwrRvAbdbouEoEbldOaBZ95fxsYV7b6UEbOcf8i0OjX33Zt5kmes6ggJp%2FZd5WgPHUsO%2FHCabCO0KJerysS0rAO%2F%2BbTdlXy1679wPAcH6C%2BQvtvf8l3YVbAFeQFWRJyuZYkGdwnJROM%2FXnLIzzR2GbzBhQF8BDS1zgC%2F%2FFwWQgyYziS6O%2BTqEHJxJ65j8eiDm0J3VsZUeXIrXfTTjbLgkU4tmtD0S3BeQwJtjLI%2B6jec2l1YcXqR6t0BqJODhaANMjLrdGVgrZOuhGXdUn0%2FsAdKExeVcf4UpRI8N9vA2gD135cCrFTbEC2tGdc%2BbDTr0vhWZ15SK5i7Dz3RbL8Gr0%2BIZbxCJV4dw%2Fdsym%2Borh%2Biw%2FlAmDcgtjr40VJBpPbSufZ2AgArldgTNhmmuGR1zYpps2ZNkLtP6JMAgaAxAS%2Bnp0vrMDh%2F8Jn3mRONjHUwed7lGZdGlELpBSdpKRiw0uupDL8vm9Nn%2BUQMGjPfC%2F2bs%2FRJRMOY%2FBt6QxLJjhgOYGH4MWaEC0SrdCT7QPF%2BZsFO7rlYbshU0wP26%2Bt1c6X5HlbME2VseGGl6FZJ7Wr9VFi6ouXjnxWyPB7tcVtBewLxbl5MDUVjJxhQC5pnOPQJIOv1JPaz1nHLHaEM5ckvYvTiMF3KOSL1uxdpOLsasuxOEggWMddaIK740GeCuUvuQNP8OtW2OcM7sWz7x9WlinPLexp2eybkCdGWRhjDWNSsmWMZqqpo5RVX5vVlrGi9tJbiVkl2Cxu3uhQK9mtrJv7Y8IYZJofN8SwRrCYNe1T%2F9RWcDfYkxdNiFKphuKV%2BIq1SurniZLmloyi4izLAdxAaFhzvAIvawRrgddL8GI7g9l3tEnoVN4YJjMuSnEO%2BudnD7ITYuUlD8Taa41iqB3U7ePSjtGGiX41toB5512X8zb%2Fe9gWd84tk05OTI820a%2BDP63oPE6DX9hRHlZtgtLi%2FbK2VSveDvw9TOEg5pjhW0FS72eCfEcfA1Atp5eDZKGC4bLITMRxvYTJ6g8vCYbghW5g%2Begj9aR5KmJdZE1LEy0kw%2BY2Vzdf441rJ4Nb%2BQ%2BxHKvIE%2FhOZNjJ0%2FcA4%2FhQ0iqLUzw7Wk91SRVqT5OhA%2F0%2BccOm3TTKjHzF5s9Z2ETiDXA5cCLq6dsrWMDf09YjDLlsawGbGvwhYCdJj8LoxeYv%2Bg499DNZrjgqKBJGJn1B0hVfh%2FVzk2aYQuTk5mefrsVGGX3GwKoFu8hOdKJpuHwlFLEfzf9zELWJ1EmRWYkLlZ3zgPhFJkBAAgTVRqjcziXF0RZW%2Fi7CGEVR1f8PJg4LFVC0XfLnk%2FJYp0Lf6E45gnnAlmst2%2FfvEPGrF34N7bud%2B%2Fh6vIQ8m5gSbmzAaMrGwlLDykPi1%2Fx%2FJr4l4axQtF5xiZpou7N4zf2ROz6rlbNHEQGJozX%2FTFSVLKLBoQTn04Yt88qduAPhciy%2F4JkDbEW2QNssrSQwps8z%2F1gEw8No9XMoXaDmADByI3jfYGlv%2B9loVw1Seh%2Bpk2R2TqdTCQ4fVJpzCLA%2F0fp99jJ0Gpb07p3r9R5Hj95LBvqjxHRVphh%2Fw6h1pex51zmbueMb6HwzO7IW%2BY7bBakbIiB0GzBqeGLTFyRUh0480NKqxxZbdJWv4A4k0n0gt6winqV7gX2pXJEtMstyNcIHH1i5is1ZJqvVfEXKTI6t1KG18grxXRXmfs2oQ8TCkrMGvpq%2FVrCR4rNAXL%2FDS2Q9vHOm5YBPSbOKFSasDnLsTcPI7RgcXHYsj18%2FOEaiQPHWdcj%2BxLvo2rJJHho0LmWz5PTXEqArHT6pCt3miU%2BcU3rwBu0vhuw3XbwnguvA7uCbbRPgDw%2BM3Rdluumi5xUyM60belTB5IM0hZ6nSs9xzKuDxaEka9UM%2BAsnnukhjKTLfElJ8xki9%2BrzoVZgfqdiiFUfRNat9P6USCF9dXahqmQeVSX7wSEL4ctHiQCzmItMKBm1nL%2Fp14QfkmaVeJlk%2FWQ3F5u1ZGOWXMxs%2Bc8M%2Bm2T1yATEGj7Rbwadtm6cE3nIx%2FYROrTvXF0jh0BWfsSbLH8lQ7f0t8EuDkUPAulGPqpCmHZtjdf5KouunMlBt39cn5uoSOAid7nOa%2BSPbh4K4aF%2BzAeR%2F7uFbC07S9XOFAqCPVS1StbkFkxhyi3nAUGI7jsyf3e7LJjil%2FIohAQs%2BLL%2Ffq0Mmi7A57B08XsUcqz3nuWHurpzJdoBAdO7jA0X74rTX2lGv1MnI3Ln0xELA5dxfjorsmuWlGOuzieAhu6SVARzKuJdECOE%2FYnR0qmxCBxsB%2BCtwWPKKvgkObzkJtcPvfjLeJs6srMiZfsYMSisdEDV10Kbq%2FpM%2BNw75Yly%2BJOD4Nxyt0ytHHpHZAnlSoZbUyXmCZOfVfTHOBdNKGS%2F9JAnj4Bv82bKoffgODpgXq4%2BsIt1Cv5YuaLD0MqoDDAokAxgpeWVMXrcDXbL1jb%2Bmhl3HilHF1mQ%2Fj2ORMfkm2GYr%2Bb2z%2FTt8O4YyNBxTvKZLeaweTHgwYx7rEoAmJmtQYNSHSpcrRsK7iMiDaxaXqas%2BJpBTFGVtY0mRk%2F%2F1M%2FtDlc2tu8EITIv5VMcQGqm0Vf9XA6NA8G2z8GSXPCaT6mGlktc%2FOebQUPnzQJ6UExBVlocq4nHiiu%2BfYqqtY1eWLCdcH4nbPumunRGv3IXurGFwrpVEOFwWnNTZRucXvnyddL0ByTavNW8%2BWUNGq3Zc9l4Gx%2Bv1D4ZA1w7bsGZOk%2Bdpg%2F0d%2B7ND7pz%2FCqL28N9%2BhqEHZW%2FiVLEl7eoaKjm5aucKoiKA93gGS2WMG3nrqkVW520BTs%2FNNseJz3F675aa6%2F6nlhg08cAe3KA8gOEcT2XRC3p9bBDV3wFu7gppIqhWoTyHVV8yck2Usp6i8FhMkR4lIwm%2BAO%2Be4RDQpwZz76W14rsaJBkF4c1%2BqbR6X%2Bz17UDwPqcEUApvJDTxvuL%2FcOqpHTZAbJkrqiEgn91kEc0psCNDmFGoQd2ciKCUmaILbH7oPY1PDPh5F338kVlBJQAVVfrQHo3YJqiLSeAFwN%2BSCfSxjLZoU2WfokqcsmUf%2B%2BpJoo2z5t8onD8y4HdwqgRrNr12tSy3kRJUYfSGWDHd0f5lDYcQLg6LhjY%2FlIfyYbsn00z5%2Bq%2BtR%2BtbgRkpZ7DwvQMs%2BgCjK6ywlhaaYq67bIR6CoInKSIY0jrrFlgYqIFpXYYWYbWEXsKLilsJjkthTy2hXJHeTSxMyL8hkbzRkE0hfI5wMmiXu4gbWiG7ix69BIw%2Bjf21aaSjgrpEPP9kj86jzuOKCGdoQlGAlIG7f22CqnbfNRQ1eFafcLrLM8XnVu0Sb%2FBZr2xCzp9K8bvqyjPcO8PMgBMHuPnGMbCbeohm0U6dcpoHxRNbtK%2Fsml20YmmVNarNMVC%2F0OCFrPwROAwkX%2FuCG9Geu9S8v6kF5Uya9QWTuuYl0mRRp%2FtntRo7E9f2zu33UyMjB%2BaRXBWUtW1K%2FDvUyQti7tPV06BK440YwQZapS%2FyRJqADCWSH8MPHVmKpjnF3PDh5E8rgHvNcXKriJGCsklVh88dV%2BeMo3NxcrHBHoE1J7hWq4hzf4iK9OVdN3vgkPPi307WmHnYr%2FV5WEMYfnw8cJU%2Fx83Bg68FNj4rYFjKklJcJMugmu4MKxB3w310ezG0p47JbMSzr%2FuPyC5Q3ARKD3T9eirCh7xQs5%2Fxn9MiqeT1%2BlUkuzYsauiwOLjhG1lxwS2zty9Elcbp5XJdRA6Umn4iDBjBUFAc8DGvILStIriiIBbTPM1ZiWCarsKNTZV2IY%2FFHzxbfgjWz78tNaxi39pxdlXShmbeYybooYhVazq%2FD7pijL8ddA90F63Q%2Bn6EiC2B2S3tlmWTfTc6SLXBzElf5vrJ4ilTiaaePrY9YJskeSW1%2FwxAl4fDtScTYHgSV9fNknFTPik8Tzk1pqdHPHZsn8dgW99BHfIM3pmUJdOug%2BHVvQLjbPc8hQxX936ThWDih2TWodl0BS2rid2ggI9AzQ5puYuD6Ru9gmORmolURPGEH3eHvxQL7y98SrSadB0234QMgUlOK8fGN7BVMdc%2FXigW9xtDJ7ZCpd2rimmH1Jy45dJNUCtct32gPotdi9ZuHWFbtmJpz43hQM5rppxxNlLF79GSVNYHakNJIk2XORz4UaPbzvY9S5ui0gOmrQ%2FOuMytTTZRnWPVOHM%2FhswE%2FPlmshWK9J3kPqXE68YNI6sMkuFrVyNJCTU4r0%2FDDkQCbX31bFP6v0hqPxBdBHZ0JibdPKQGpmKA5nVm%2BEaH5kK9GY2h6gxkTwPldufJ%2BCTQ8PCWRo9%2FlI%2FFtHJA5JQfQXEv6KJQBO%2FUhbSrGHqr9qnq8wG8H5j5Jdj3u%2BDkso8PIzcfIbcc7S1Tu0Q%2FNE1H%2BnMOkvd89VN%2BIyxk1T1s0OikEqi0ggjTvU3YugDBKJ%2B430s2kk%2F%2Fmlnj5eQ60VLGJH6Z7wEID%2FFxk3J7zeN8Doy84X0zIN9p03ZRnMpoqxYPatO8Odk6awwsWS31Gg3oYsdTHjjGC%2FSevHdGO0fvvt0RdJscugoThJB4NrvIFAIvalw3fFvji63vVaXCpIuCRRb6vmInW0NxsX5gES9FMal7wAZnZJFJ%2B6LZeTrlSiZOzBT8xCsng9AHD%2B5vh7bOdgi3PCkNLi59jC2v%2Bl7AtG30jx93qijqo53%2BxBJMnKM%2FFnTwnrfQkU5HqyC12BgF6TRwoyVY3Kf9Im2M4vLKfu0%2F%2FmWIZgoZnglKLnHYM3OOznop0GzUsTnP0gql3GLVT3Y1Tm%2BI2dOnZqCMJvwF%2BHc1hZ9sVe7UaNNJBQ8MQLzxjV1YcErHy88a4AmssH%2B2ejhtx%2F6GMhBml05h36jQjqqhv4mz382n8YZiHiWWEJryVLVPYDCFSQtSpaULt8Ml1ZXWJbgkg7GDNC3%2FrBTEEutxy%2FpBWdIokTSAVFMTTOXoYJu0w%2BYt9jrd1wCfAOnB24zg83Y5dp5uUAuYAQ%3D%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=15FCE702&__EVENTVALIDATION=PTqGt0ZBPKHngplkbT0fddtV4nDkH%2FyJup62GnhEtTaEtk1spFvujKBm1XbJV6iflrfJS1jOIEoh5bHvDHAUjKCA4lD%2BgU6XHR%2BSwNyDkZX6T5udkCdBk%2B7WgUEX3uRS4ycQn%2FcCb4wDEJ13dYNubSOYfM5Uion3%2BknOFXj6%2FCvzwPH08RxQH3iVexWVkF6%2BNYxZySFRITTOQAh5xHsDAqYrqE%2Fk68%2BAB3JSXJAYNo0AqwpFPDsRVE4nFB5Y%2BhSjNsm%2BepmqYu8QFXhYucEsfFUinBq7HT7jQgehrzjeiX5Z4jcnEb45o%2FFhH%2Baqzxr%2BvP4Ck4cDXY4LTNjB5Odx21xMCabqsVf0Cgqo3TjEtsZdhwWfwF2%2F9alf0%2BKo7900ItUfwqVe1aUt4o8wr9n6pWYqLcPUt6qV5YOO%2BV7%2FgEeKzMLEXhhv2zHBEHrnCZu7299Fo8iDEXDkpzymJK5RA0XQSFunpoxdinS9%2BphUe2CTtCy3%2BGTmigrr%2F%2BQZWNYIMrt2KACxu9NfSGZxLZgky05bXq4CFQYv7CIYVPgFgy6VT%2F6ASt9gqE3gFRJmHn7CwXLu1uNdS11VsGuGbXWPkz7%2ByvoNMjKDHg6bmDprAGJQnhphdj9Adv%2B5mcBw4Jn%2FfJmId5smx6dm5P9oWm%2BbXUsCggjS1NewLb0S6k6BpQWDq3spr7r3z8AHkOLGooJK2o2UazKusM0THyVJ%2BbnSazbUtevgyZ7r4S45Rsd45ushngpzvg%2FdwIIThXiR1kstht9dKMhRXwkGjnbw5tC4qTHevI15H5JurNTUtggeGQKP9mvzpDQhlQe98VrJ5AaZA94N6xvAkpmkqpsqH%2FaFRgfNGXB0anvlWB70N8DZset6tGRPrNBFt73OvekIKr%2BKZa0l319CerquV7y%2B5HGRGmV7Z2LBL61mS5JYfbBP%2FjhfFiG19Wfs9GTI6kfKY07flffSA3OSn3m%2BIqlTRec1KY0x3%2BsmdI41GCSYpd4efbxLlFg08%2BeD8OOmmgWe0Ve%2Bp2vxEAz9wwnC0v3XgIfFVJIvERygbJ%2BY6Eof93YAp%2B5fp8YnbnG%2Fq1Vc3wgtpa9KDgPLObFAs8PDNSVQF0FYZbQ4CGH3BjIHywLYIqubLk7i8yM0svyn4dZvmDBAaoh9NyLiVsZTkVzzrhPR3nVektzuDxUAfwr3LMDv%2FXP9q7gStIloAUxMoCK66tyVauvFD6wyohtdPKS%2BhA6qcULADM3MNscybizQLPuyQcFFB47z41N6TrQpj8Q%2BIaBWlRbrFimVqw4F8Q9Mb1zl%2FU1m0dXi62hF8J8VVBHpuqjJ5nG5v5OACfVclxrsd37X1q7BvI%2Bd4Dv5fbp7hZ%2BEqXAY0XZjxiCCHO8GqEbyTOLQgyCOVAVBIdcKY7zF1Hury0biavygwugGqBpaG%2BEKFUmWX9H95si5rVV9HxHjJw3Yl61qaHYDCYsXxcopmW3nuFIwHTTiPywFc1MTcTk5UuLzkirRhku6sE09QCCISA9I0SGJbfzhenQTKztBjF25Xh%2BaGb3j2JZ4AEiQYr8dQbkPNsh3120AR%2B2eGg3Qj3Io4AVKoJB4ow1CPdbXLreoSILB%2FCNBd9G4ZraQLQlvyPQmA0SonE%2F%2B5QioJfgmjqa6X22tOU0G%2BP81j5kgFSKBpYrYGu48Z%2FlCBSr%2B802Eyvft9eLD%2FuPB5z9yql9TLTnj5p8s5uC3PV8cO%2F99nFVel17CkeZ%2FCQay7C50Wmp3VG9xXqfEvrS1dv2bk8tEghMxBba4Vc1Vuxv0O6hDSGfEXOkPhmn2VYltODZ6XSeVPFcB1FkjHbr3bBkrs9hlFKGsyTjVsBUJKR%2BCfuiKuJyl7hX%2FKJ8McQteb8w9uezaJxfbQg8uBmrgpVIWqin3phJDwGe3g%2FifFCEjwRH%2BkYepjEdx1tKQvVyzvU9vD7HaZYsfUYpPKG6jIP1ela8JKxauo102kGnjnzb8C0%2B5hty1wV%2BfjoCHQ53ziNQlgHnAqyryP%2Fdax7VPCX1onjSmXqYzp4EjHXq9DEBBi98DC%2B3siCmL1Ms72A1MvqPHzCx9ejF4ofDSKaRRoELX4QjjtwKEbOf%2FTHEl9uTRRDjEyrtpDPcNg6XQ8VsDEn8HaJvlM%2BjnwwJjPlN%2FqcKgyb9fDSNhx2aJ%2BtTeGQStiO0jbsUyKFT3Ei9Xl8XoqbzjT%2FSsBU1QidPuijNFuFckEn4c0%2FR4mSBeMEH2kCR4Sgf72c%2F52ekJu%2FOSeUM6bRmWrz68OyLX%2BTkYCt%2BaUNE60447UnSURpuoRldd2vISACRutMVWYzv2DzeBOBz77ins6Pi2q%2BHibrjVqGO25f9rzDfcNneh2Hb%2BFDfNbGETiGbsVnJT0UsRs39%2Fe2qJQzoNrVXpyd4p7Hh%2B34LMwEbvs58CF9pDdU%2Fk9MDF0D7Ls7maRitWeW0fPCpNVosrKGFqZz8vfDuEKTgZLkvJ1DBrU4rHtbx7iif30riwlYaP58uTsT1d3zEjbpbFJFq3Pzt8MH25KIYNIlDxyEkrJhjkHWvKhOrcWbOwt74ZthPDran1a%2BTVlEu6TwDvLgr0lqwOooabCf7Sfch5G0Wmy6dYNeeze4nKDNu79AO8aWrgIiiESw%2Bv19jvrjm8cheoQm9kkleLz3mIZoDZTf0Iy9LcYGc%2FPUGVgIjQ%2FPtNgYwRHrtgarYIch5iRa85a9JAPIb0Nxe3q3nNCXca1w8LTBQp188DJTBdSkY%2FFwIYsmD6yWM9SksIQxV0Mkp0%2FtLhNdcZun3K606GzYKnnQcffNG8xj5mtwUmoDknc%2FQT4NrQlMK1wPjzLbGgjlcetpCVS3i%2BBWuPB1ZzmoX4jAfnFdRQ2al7Whz3xAHloIzLQGTwMp0ZJ75Gos81%2F3yryxbZfrtvTtEouNJHsTHqqOANJr6en6O5UaficjGuDQp%2FCM%2FsMI%2FWF3RXNdqzvpCp%2F2BdupmajHx3aa3EdeT9Uu13ziRMGsyPOYNKEyOSOypLpl7R%2BTTN2HVgmgZoexjg6nx5huk3Vi%2FY2%2B47X7WJ9HKSVjcR8HBrPuHyqXkw2t%2B3mzzC1bb5EwtP%2BGL7lpt2PXsl%2Fukzp4t7CTaIPvWnbo8RhodMyABkenjPg10pq4hfrBOKWiPUkn0vrVQF%2Bvn8BazhA3Twn7JDeMqcwmOX8baCXpJ11hp%2BMhFa0%2FCttg2gAa1pjFcS8CUM3N4AUWTY0JPfAd8dEdkhDvTHBMcpA5d4sWOMjgTHEVw4BYA5pUlXVETIyooFGqcOwZRNYF6cYLx7KtkO9Uoc6sQVFu4konTBuQQcvxDRBhum0g7JcjSGUQ%2B7le%2FLW%2BfpjcuQ9Nmz784d1offPinxDiwY%2FzZ9AO9uqB%2BsV%2FmeU8jmS84%2BC7y9yiz%2B%2B5TuGKpAm%2BhObm4Z8FC7EddIGOkcffhZsIhUw5Fu8UCoGtDyNBGroSjqzqE3THw%2BEmBxm4%2F4EpX7QaJdC4iE1Mr5ICaqYPzeqiH4TLHeseNtzlN47UA3gh93VZ1nzbgdA1SaRiRKmE7nXIdAJUECGgQL%2FSAOTSqvPMYzB7DPb8YALwG5TsmrLJZb9QzFfA745hzpzV3YZHZfKT5ghPHLmjRw6Tsbl9U8x0l5if20qi5CmwxYSBJa2Qr1D1W%2F2h9IEjv5nYgVOkAVCu1Gv8PG1uCwbZ86sixX6Cg2d30i4NhLJ8%2B0F6pKfSDiDapIWVbXnnpaHm8isVwWNDcmLSTbes%2By9W9cQdi9zI7Ze57ReGjR7MuR7axyZi%2FFE4l1hWELqat22URPfWsFU7oBiT9%2FzaZ3pipdLPeonzLsG5KzLuuwrnXVAUNg%2Fsp6%2FVurSfKyIJFgcgvhuRX84AmJ5oHyM%2FEr8c2O%2BzvcOUwDUAr6rYtqRKqNLEiETQ5t2DzD6pjxkUpC9mPhcoZFZptoYPIUqcIYc%2FgLXS3CYWcnCXZSrsKFpruh0ZaqT9K%2BNlYtHN3LS0%2FmR%2FBZnFHbhNEdaDUQfCi%2BVs7VwrMtj%2BlzcoYjNYsARe3ynslji7C2ItSgQ3IR7HLdKAx4hCHB42lOLUJgSvHMOqRn0l%2FbyBSnoU%2BwE%2Fu6FR%2Fn5ZH0j3IqJjiRbeklmXYrJnVQO%2B37emXGecmY6BimxER%2F%2FtJlYuZrrhsoRgXFtpy3zS6sOg%2BcJHte6WuhOCgE3zJebu3kB4AESDh5IqD7jHrxcFHmhtXhU7Hzv4e8MajgV%2BKMwph27vjPFas9pUUq2T5Lkye3qC%2Bbnm9Se4nf0cNj9D1cMbrHSS9Cw44d2FWZ%2FnTpgdbZwEn4O94ICFdSg%2FqNdDBRK0%2BD4CPCa3oKP8d1wPSety2dl2yozACkPo1NML8piGVQRhevHxwVhTLjHuPz7IM%2Fvmo6JTAOp7PyUiOXeqWQGTnwYXCBiiiVvEZP8vRuAIpZSRn7rIXQ3451lChltGef5j9sXyaFqomzi1kE0A0AWyfV%2BueKyKy8P8Ib%2FzN7TZORWXSeo9Uc0DyMVpXWPO8F4x7QBKFGbzf5Guc6nWQGgxQgG%2BL6HSjidNh4WgIJpOxzJCtptVHqrR0FFUZyPmlwS9EcaN2USvNtNVVqhjo3Rw3QkKzBSdZSQdoxyDVdnktbFPoplrx6z17MpQaLUeSRMq7KHkVYtlJb6rG7pL%2F2GBeh9kqD4GQlK02Hgw35lESF96hp3EqOtlvrbMS1ObseNxTAPfUkHjB50Fa6PXcRQ4PHnOOQ%2Bg%2Bv%2FD2KSyK%2BaGtNnZWhWpszCINCmvF1C%2BcvnH6OOUA0VSwcSv%2B%2Bjl2usVQRZ9HwHMKRy9MTHKQKUKx8w%2BdsdJZ45xoPoeoapd%2BkU7zO%2FrPSBUL6PktKgcVWE33vU%2FE5cjtClGXJryYZazuoIOVg2jLB979l0wEkB%2Beo6NTiWP3DKRmdyFIozbSqK9PpM9YMZcajr31LI%2Ba2TWEdUYo3h78vI2U3Y7F4c0NjCYaqAJjzxcGM%2FbmpdrNxoiznzBk4pbnTKOBixfhIC%2BNLrcth3xhulmF6oaw8MP8X9IdeRA5sypPC93fviAULXPxdaQGQQk9SA0HwcbDS48l%2Fd%2B4xH5%2FehTPnZMPeofAHnDSc1pVGu5WBy%2FbMY9Y8XQvYBxZXD2oN7Osu1zmwChEao8ZZSOgZXc211bMQ1BrlaVXeL2LoZRVE3j7FDFp0jQzWtwBLpV%2BLNRegDzGhNhQzPG%2FnQOOTIn5nspGzGPDyOVUIgY0JpgBDoIsG5zft%2BKYj5xeEWC7lep%2Bg7wZlkyDRt5LrBBSqKAWfpAYFpQmupDx%2BUSH%2FP1Gued3EWw0nDxK4iAHL5ed6E2piEJTZbmhFgXkjaRJ6k0VvhIE6ODl618M%2B25f%2FrKaMqKAhBYe4oNWZqeVhI8Y6L96dSA3qjYCW%2Bbe%2BMOtmRYr81m7k%2BEMOF2v1%2BLVyUxDjOX%2BROVCJp6xyYsM1T5azD9eLayS2ZAHtMRnssyeO8r4fr7JH1HEPYUBTMNyzn%2FgQUCyhH%2BKX6frTmkoJfEc1qH6OxRZW212mC7mR5sLqxCC7NiWxGlhAG47mMFci%2BGGFwLh%2B%2FvTseMvwwGahYx3fVq0Gao9HzkQW%2FE5ZN4spwoT%2FppVanSDOYSXjUsD1VENdXEp3VB0M5G4M7ml16UwMhm87fDem8eTivmFyZHQi01oTAxfUu9hYpGAf3KwT2RZV5qCMeKIzHNIfH6jeKz3wi1WEOyv6HQKZwxh6Q%2FLDuLk8%2B3SrtN6Z1G66PK7nd6ehNoqf7AD0zszCh%2FulWl%2BpQAYtZUTwJcaoecj9i5l%2Fk%2BcnWtF2OQsoQl%2FtdeeaqxFCAGhYatC3vsqdnaeDpNqqyNkwTTtTkGbpF%2Bw5TM7kDTINn1tlFdv1VDqyCxptdGlT%2BKpyNaj5GgkdBdnpVrgPsaJfaV6uMVRYDvdvFTeOiasqq6kBZp7hwSfZf%2FuXVlD4BcR6ru67BlD82yijsNFa2nTMbygpGMErvHm9ND%2Brp%2BAw4uCJJ8OS1WLkuROBf9pISOKgUdRY5tQCQzndIEMU9EnvoIjC8SKbCZWOZBjHHWczB3r507mrzmKrq8J9r7%2FhO1WFgoOVgB%2BfPQCooLZxWZoH0IsDvFUPg5cd9qp%2Fh%2B8kwOEzg7BMgEKhRnm6o0c7cybAbABTpLxUle%2FTCcybG5%2F2qHhK89gkt%2BvLdv4FrfRwYUiEJHuuHymk3%2F6oZyu2IQFIjwUcfdJT1LGMT%2FSnZHZkgAqJmcuiVvlSN1TDcoLYeyyV1Urs2qHB4PHXHZHdSD26x9v6DcyiSaae8Fs9yy9xuHJ%2BhDsNCPcaaqtHu1f4Of5sQwWbFSUPtkeERwmVsWe%2FV%2BDlHKCR1DCBzhpLIa%2Ft%2F4blRUXmhmT4QSsAcYP35os7iboNpbOMZ5kWrR3NqkrxWxqH%2Bu38Yj%2B6eCA1SolLcS9nlYfH74rGQRtwxsIYNkj1BfhNf%2BrmrnWYy50atexJLCcZKCdoZrbhed6PwwssYw2Cor%2FloNV5NL7paBWAXrKimO9cFkNZKAS10fhEhvkffvmQTD5926OgtJLgFnVEJt4IL7muhMEJBK9wRgtLeEnY7g0HJZH3CQAHdoOBTjEuMZ7Z2drvB%2Fg0niNXulCBN5C%2FB%2F2UV6b07qX7wB9vG2yxAWvHM14EndI29fIPrzB8z5U67rKomwhTMy53Or4zB%2BNBvxg%2BOU21%2F%2FWpf%2F0K8TSyno1MZ7kpC6EvkoIOPOCt3iBwsvY1lGTIZA%2FeFEeEaXmCoSpXatyKNCTrfQbiBEenQnqqYqnUjLvV%2Fho6yhxX5mKihvOltEZrIz2yOIO0a%2F%2Fm5BMzYRgZer046Y85LwrS7FK8vG1BoWXB7roU6r6tPws49Mk4ipLVj%2FkBLei6YDz262FBeyI%2BbDG0l48bu36YAyCGs6WacKAq6SwYZYvEn2xmvmCt4FlvHQ%2BQEyl7pYad6I9TeHnIswFT16D9RZ%2BUogeThj8FviO7JWTfMM3bVv7zupJ1CCSC1ssa1iKzfAfTLmolZOmOijrSHCAlDsnWSY2EcVsd35JyA0M%2BZ5h28v9DdUTbd3eaj7d%2FtPyjaH%2BNduL3bAbnJ3gOUKU2r%2FSDeXYmAPxiOiokL6rI3UMlVTo5s0en7v%2BdF8Ig3ajIoWAe6iiT6q%2BQAm3XiPnNS2j77SGE1GX4zf3cHCoCFR9DiIcvQOtunzc%2BLy2lIdmsSTt06Jy00qlAJLcNbaqlBIU51hjG0a63qWotwmXYgXcy1r8EnZ6CpdQdi1nSh6Z%2Be8ReuZPU33JYaXv3XhtXgskZR9%2BLRbZE7VyipRlgbbatmzz3nn0WJ46bt2WPG6f2E2Epm%2BHYks9849VCoFW1abI7d7mXSNA8zwR%2F8k339fJtm8MtgvOiLGSBarwj5Hv%2ByM0NDrfkSvgECnOV%2BU0y5gWjpN%2FPX2o9JaH1usYee%2FM2y%2F%2BDozjySzdOY6M%2F3RyUoXXWl9YZ87rPghiXs9OG9XjRQyEZNKswyu50azx6f98lQpIwuXa35N%2FR56uTkTzfmRqBH2r%2BlZT4SaHOZVPV%2B4CLtEwxN4GVHsKSfBQ2gWzgkOQ7cvIY0Ft86fQlHuUF3xy1NNTgRTeLakzI%2F8xSYC4UgLFRcN%2BuhXAkKv56a0hypuq%2BVTCxz2FKSxMP%2F4raiCk939XDd2rrIvJ4C2oe7dX6gvVTgzmXJOumFhRA4mtdQvYWlq0pgRie6BiNEoQuTeH%2FrOe%2BJJnVnNc%2BVmeYMKNBD8DYRi8N%2B9MU2h4gM%2BKWslxiGE4ME4I6if3z2yzc57a%2FIMZvFWvsuhEhQOFY9GLeBBjyjlii1tjJwjJ2yUKyxt5MdEWrhtQCs0wBiQBi0fa1fN20jQe48j1SATX%2BTgVwDO0fXVlceGlGZicaE6ANBk%2B5nTIgWLl7K2sPQUSHxRcQBr1p2eLL6c%2Bvd2Qd5LfueBFHPkGfsvNcBRgBMAtPDGVS8EQfbuYzzYRX%2Fwir0UaZGG7wftlReikTFqbq4butvKPzWT%2FE7um6ZCB5ZG4HUMD0CU00wvz0%2BEC8KT6lFXtEcZfQMiDWmKx66yP39LtvlRXSEGx6YqnOhUnueGmZK1jRGoVsyQS9Po1l40JnfFKe2gN7zxXvFu4Y9AgbHPzCbeaNVxa%2FOGkZ5Hpk1RjC1onwAZM8CqRG%2BZmsEk3lnJNTPCTtp59luTey%2FcFmECvFWO08IN4KVM1eeKZuTvO3c4rjCl5pqe%2BgP0mNBK1c2y2H95pFPS1lKmpAXSS5rXmNt%2BT4Zu9BWnUp5yDC2hi8zp8mbkBaWIsHsNNFLHD7a0QXKI5ek6W9YLpnoRCXjG5chDBT2BMit15KlWYjBnjUOEYHVC5cU2fe%2Fo9N6pc%2B%2FH5B%2FoQ5LA00TyQ1VJPLrdwSamzrJw%2Bmx%2B3temsN%2ByNuiwiVbGnM3wUJIPwt1LrpaFLAd69RfUJDqvWtNfxFctPo%2FJM9&__ASYNCPOST=true&'

headers = """Host: apps.who.int
authority: apps.who.int
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="94", "Google Chrome";v="94", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
cache-control: no-cache
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
x-microsoftajax: Delta=true
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
accept: */*
origin: https://apps.who.int
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
referer: https://apps.who.int/flumart/Default?ReportNo=12
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=bnx31vt1hsfsldihuszbk452; BIGipServerpool_apps.who.int_http=rd2o00000000000000000000ffff9ee80c4eo80; TS01ac0ef4=015dd60f3e1f352f15a41d299fd9ecd7a082e0b85eb62504deed1220d15a2f9bb946cec46693ae3a5e8d2733baff23250470302f28f8d768bf0028a5807d15b3cf9569ac54cf66bc629d7233dd96a586a1ceb17a95
Content-Length: 24277"""
```

---

```py
data = data_format('United States of America', 2020, 2, 2020, 9)
print(parse_table(soup(get_page_data(parse_headers(headers), data), 'html.parser')))
```

Due to the character limits on Stack Overflow posts, the output from the script can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Ajax12345/fb0f7fa2ad8b1fcd4a74b5110f5c7c3f).

#### Important Note

In practice, the code above is just the start. @Geoff has created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/gfairchild/be93ff6998cec77e749a4cf70ce96384) that outlines how to programmatically access a number of essential headers that are vital to returning an accurate response from the site.

Comment: Thanks so much! This does indeed seem to work just fine. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Geoff Glad to help!

Comment: Dang, this was working great earlier, but I'm trying to run this code again and am now getting an error. It looks like this: "ASP.NET session has expired or could not be found". I'm guessing it has to do with the `cookie` header parameter, but I'm not sure. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: @Geoff That is because the header and cookie data was generated for a session that ultimately expired. If you go back to the page, run any report query, and capture the new session data (I think all you need to grab is the cookie), you should have programatic access restored.

Comment: Is this something we could use a `requests.Session` for since `Session` objects can store cookies?

Comment: @Geoff Yes, for example, `requests.Session().get('https://apps.who.int/flumart/Default?ReportNo=12').cookies.get_dict()` produces `{'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'qpsw1ljftloe520eshel1s0a', 'BIGipServerpool_apps.who.int_http': 'rd2o00000000000000000000ffff9ee80c4eo80', 'TS01ac0ef4': '015dd60f3ec3ecdbd988e59a6b16e4f38ba0248f03996afaa4156a8d425b15895751b3cac5a26ade8b4a6257a7f2b06c0208b38751b7ee84a3055918871e433c2556ecd850d2cc386d532c64de1e09cc08a3f053a4'}`

Comment: Niiiiice, that's really helpful!

Comment: I've got this *so close* to working, but I'm having an issue with getting the cookies/POST payload correct. https://gist.github.com/gfairchild/be93ff6998cec77e749a4cf70ce96384 is my current code, and when I run it, I get this: `0|error|500||`. AFAIK, I need to capture the cookies, `__VIEWSTATE`, `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR`, and `__EVENTVALIDATION` from the HTML and include all of that in the POST request. I just can't seem to get this working. Do you see what I might be doing wrong? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Actually, I was just able to solve this! It turns out that 3 requests in total are required to fully automate this (a GET followed by 2 POST requests). I was missing the middle POST request, which is why I was stuck. My GitHub Gist above contains the full working code. Thanks, @Ajax1234!

Comment: @Geoff Glad to help, and good to hear you were able to find a solution! I have updated the post with a note at the bottom, including the link to your Gist.